# Ubuntu Studio 19.04 shutdown suspend restart issues

Tags: suspend, shutdown, 19.04, ubuntu-studio

I just installed Ubuntu Studio 19.04 on an old Acer Aspire E1-510. It seemed to be working mostly fine, but it seems that upon trying to suspend, shutdown, or restart the system, it would get stuck on a black screen and I would have to force shut down by long pressing the power button. 
I thought I might've messed up the system when I was trying to get polybar and conky to work, so I reinstalled from scratch, but the problem still persists.

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

I have a machine identical to yours. It has the same problem, and none of my other machines (two Dells and a Thinkpad) have this issue, so I have always suspected it's a hardware/BIOS incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try blacklisting `dw_dmac`, and `dw_dmac_core`, then adding the following code to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

Comment: I tried this, doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: darh.  was anyone able to fix this?  I can confirm the same issue on swift 3 laptop, with upgraded bios (upgraded to latest version in may 2019).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same issue on acer swift 3/ubuntu 19 with bios ugpraded to latest version ~ may 2019.

Additionally the OS freezes up quite a bit for a split second or two, every few mins, due to picue sending over too many requests to the cpu or something of that sort (issue described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726100/pci-nomsi-noaer-in-etc-default-grub-any-downside)).  I haven't tried implementing this solution on my machine, since i was told it could screw up the whole machine by not allowing it to boot from the ssd.